# Sending appropriate input to plugin

Tags: javascript, html, json, algorithm, plugins

I am using a third party javascript plugin to develop a two-column table functionality as per my requirements. The plugin accepts an input `json` array which looks something like the following:

```
var data = {"Project" : [{'Start':'02/20/2012',
'End':'02/20/2012',
'Content':'Project Description',
'Group' : 'Table Group 1'
},...
] };
```

`Group` in the above `json` when used in the plugin can be given any type of content (`custom html content as well`) which it renders internally as:

```
var items = []; //json array items will be pushed by items.push from input `data` json
for(var i=0,im = items.length;i<im;i++){
var group = items[i].Group;
groupDiv.innerHtml = group;
}
```

In my case, to the `Group` item of the `json array` item, I am passing a custom HTML which looks like the following:

```
var customHtml = '<div><span class="button-red"></span>'+
                       '<div class = "quick-info-hide">' + 
                       'Some Custom Content from input' +
                       '</div></div>'
```

I am generating this `customHtml` from some input (another larger json) and sending it to the plugin and was trying not to modify the plugin itself. However, I had to modify the plugin to add a certain functionality here (row expansion `on/off`) which is kind of troubling me now.

When the row is not expanded, customHtml's `span` and `div` should have class `style1`, and if it expanded, customHtml's `span` and `div` should have class `style2`. 
However, inside the plugin, `customHtml` is assigned without any `if condition` of expansion/collapse. Since the plugin was not built with a logic of `row expansion/collapse on click`, it wasn't expected to do so as well. I want to change the styles here on expansion/collapse to assign to `groupDiv.innerHtml` i.e customHtml which probably can be done by another variation of `customHtml1` which will have different styles.

What is the best approach to do this? 
Should I add an `if condition` here and send two variations of `customHtml` in the plugin and apply the suitable one on respective if `condition`? Is there a better method as well in this case to not spoil the generic approach of the plugin (which I seem to be doing here with modification)?

Comment: That's not a JSON string, but a simple JavaScript object - here in literal notation.